# MySQL Connector/J not converting SQL DATE to the time zone of the JVM

Tags: java, mysql, date, jdbc, timezone

Assume the following conditions are met:

1. Both hosts (the one running *JVM* as well as that running *MySQL*) have their hardware clocks running in UTC, and these clocks are synchronized (e. g.: using NTP).
2. The time zones of *MySQL* and the *JVM* are **different** (in my example, *MySQL* is running in `Europe/Moscow` (`+03:00`) time zone and the *JVM* is using `GMT+14:00`).

In this case there will be periods during each day when the current date representation (in `yyyy-MM-dd` format) will be different from Java and database perspectives (database date will be lagging behind).

I'm using *MySQL Connector/J* 8.0 which is time zone aware by default (as opposed to 5.1.46), so it should be sufficient to just set `serverTimezone` connection property to `Europe/Moscow`, in case the driver is unable to parse `@@time_zone` and/or `@@system_time_zone`.

Now, consider the following scenario:

1. The client stores the current time stamp (as an instance of `java.sql.Timestamp`) to the database.
2. The same client then reads just the *date fraction* of the above time stamp (as a `java.sql.Date`) back into the JVM.

The date fraction read is expected to be *converted* back to the time zone of the JVM (this is what I'm observing for *Oracle*, *PostgreSQL* and *MS SQL Server*), i. e. the following test should succeed:

```
import static java.lang.String.format;
import static java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.TimeZone;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public final class TimeZoneTestPartial {
    private static final TimeZone DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+14:00");

    private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sandbox";

    private static final Properties CONNECTION_INFO = new Properties();

    static {
        CONNECTION_INFO.setProperty("user", "...");
        CONNECTION_INFO.setProperty("password", "...");
        CONNECTION_INFO.setProperty("useSSL", "false");
        CONNECTION_INFO.setProperty("serverTimezone", "Europe/Moscow");
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpOnce() {
        TimeZone.setDefault(DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE);
    }

    @Test
    @SuppressWarnings("static-method")
    public void testDate() throws SQLException {
        try (final Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, CONNECTION_INFO)) {
            try (final Statement stmt = conn.createStatement()) {
                final String tableName = "date_with_time_zone_test";
                try {
                    stmt.executeUpdate(format("drop table %s",
                            tableName));
                } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") final SQLException ignored) {
                    // ignore
                }

                stmt.executeUpdate(format("create table %s (value %s not null)",
                        tableName,
                        getTimestampType()));

                final long clientTimeMillis = currentTimeMillis();

                try (final PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(format("insert into %s (value) values (?)",
                        tableName))) {
                    pstmt.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(clientTimeMillis));
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                }

                final String selectSql = format("select * from %s", tableName);
                try (final ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery(selectSql)) {
                    assertThat(rset.next()).isTrue();
                    final Date date = rset.getDate(1);
                    assertThat(date).isNotNull();
                    assertThat(rset.next()).isFalse();

                    final SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    format.setTimeZone(DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE);
                    assertThat(format.format(date))
                            .as("date fraction from the database")
                            .isEqualTo(format.format(new java.util.Date(clientTimeMillis)));
                }

                stmt.executeUpdate(format("drop table %s",
                        tableName));
            }
        }
    }

    private static String getTimestampType() {
        return "datetime"; //"timestamp";
    }
}
```

In effect, the test **fails** for *MySQL* -- i. e., unlike other mainstream databases, the *MySQL* driver may return a yesterday date: if I store an `SQL TIMESTAMP` and read back an `SQL DATE`, the date fraction will have the time zone of the database, not that of the JVM.

Am I missing something here?

How do I configure *MySQL Connector/J* 8.0 so that it behaves consistently with other JDBC drivers?

Comment: If, for diagnostic purposes, you use SimpleDateFormat to format both values as both date and time (instead of just date) are they 11 hours apart? Also, have you tried  GMT+10:00 instead of GMT+14:00 just to rule out the edge case? (GMT+14:00 is somewhat obscure. I tried setting my MySQL server time zone to '+14:00' and it wouldn't let me.)

Comment: Something does seem to be a bit odd with `rset.getDate(1)`. Using  a variety of `DEFAULT_TIME_ZONE` values I'm able to get a proper round-trip with `rset.getTimestamp(1)`, but `rset.getDate(1)` is giving me different results.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL TIMESTAMP and DATE types do not contain timezone information.

Similarly, the java.util.Date, java.sql.Date, and java.sql.Timestamp types do not contain timezone information.  java.util.Date and java.sql.Timestamp contain the number of milliseconds since Jan. 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC.

Their `toString` methods make use of the system default timezone, but that does not affect their values.

Since timezone information is not meaningful in Date or Timestamp data, you should not be using it in your comparisons.

Do not compare the values using their String forms.  Do not use SimpleDateFormat at all.  Instead, compare the actual, meaningful data that each represents, by using a comparison that is not affected by timezones.

The easiest way to do this is by converting the data to the less ambiguous [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate()) and [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toLocalDateTime()) types:

```
LocalDateTime localClientTime = new Timestamp(clientTimeMillis).toLocalDateTime();
assertThat(date.toLocalDate())
        .as("date fraction from the database")
        .isEqualTo(localClientTime.toLocalDate());
```